# Selectable axis labels on highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

Hi guys i have the following script displaying a chart

```
`$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            },
            enableMouseTracking: false
        }
    },
    series: [{
       {
        name: 'London',
        data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
    }]
});
});`
```

The chart is displaying well, but i'm not able to select axis labels when passing mouse on it, it displays like an image,  i need to know is their a way to make labels selectable.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this option is not available, because charts are based on SVG not HTML elements.

Comment: Is there another way to get the label value from another elements like tooltip... ?

Comment: You can use [labels formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter) and then check possible references or use your own.